# Usage of the compound preposition "para con"

Tags: preposiciones, uso-de-palabras

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_prepositions#Compound_prepositions) mentions that *para con* is rarely used, but I hear it often enough to warrant this question.

On the other hand, the Wikipedia article references the [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=A) with respect to the use of *a por* and *por*.

When is the compound preposition *para con* preferable to just using *con*?

Comment: Why was the nice general [tag:usage] tag discarded and only this unnecessarily narrow [tag:word-usage] tag kept? This question is the perfect example where the former works and the latter does not, since it's about a phrase rather than a word. "Term" could be used to cover both, but plain old "usage" is also perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaime, there's simply no rule or case when *para con* is preferable than *con*  or simply *para*.

Remember that *para con* is just a formal preposition combination (I'll agree that rarely used), but its emphatic meaning make it well suited for its use within legal documents (just to super-clarify). Anyway, you can just use *hacia*, *en relación a* or just *para*.